# Why can I write Guess{value:1000} when value is private?

Tags: rust, visibility

I have a code like this from the offical tutorial book Chapter 9.3

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    pub struct Guess {
        value: i32,
    }

    impl Guess {
        pub fn new(value: i32) -> Guess {
            if value < 1 || value > 100 {
                panic!("Guess value must be between 1 and 100, got {}.", value);
            }

            Guess { value }
        }

        pub fn value(&self) -> i32 {
            self.value
        }
    }

    let g = Guess{
        value:1000
    };
    println!("{}", g.value);
}
```

According to the book I should not be able to create a `Guess` using the `let g = Guess {}`  However, this code does not cause any error and prints `1000`
There is still a problem even if I put the `struct` and `impl` outside the main func like this and delete the pub keyword.

```rust
struct Guess {}
impl Guess {}
fn main() {}
```

Comment: A private structure will be unreachable if you try to use it from another module, but as everything is defined in the main file there is no question of private/public.

Comment: *According to the book* — please link to / quote the section of the book that says that. That will let us either clarify what it means or correct a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the book I should not be able to create a Guess using the `let g = Guess {}`

It is unlikely that the book states that.

Rust visibility works in terms of modules, anything in a module can see all the contents of their parents regardless of their pub status; the reverse is not true.

Since `main` and `Guess.value` are in the same module, there is no barrier. Moving `Guess` out of `main` doesn't change that, they're still in the same module. For visibility to become an issue, `Guess` needs to be moved into a separate non-ancestor module (e.g. a sub-module, or a sibling).

Example:

```rust
pub struct Foo(usize);

pub mod x {
    pub struct Bar(usize);
    impl Bar {
        pub fn get(&self) -> usize { self.0 }
    }
    pub fn make(n: super::Foo) -> Bar {
        // can access Foo's fields because this is a
        // descendant module, so it is "part of" the
        // same module
        Bar(n.0)
    }
}

pub fn qux(n: x::Bar) -> Foo {
    // Can't access Bar's field because it's not exposed to this module
    // Foo(n.0)
    Foo(n.get())
}
```

Comment: I think I understand it. The link of the book is `https://kaisery.github.io/trpl-zh-cn/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html#%E5%88%9B%E5%BB%BA%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E7%B1%BB%E5%9E%8B%E8%BF%9B%E8%A1%8C%E6%9C%89%E6%95%88%E6%80%A7%E9%AA%8C%E8%AF%81` (It's a Chinese version of the tutorial). I think I just misunderstood the book.